# Form update only first ID

Tags: php, html, forms

This is Bootstrap popup (fade) form, and i have list of all members and the button next to them, and when you click, you can edit the profile of specified user (id). Everything works fine except `<div class="modal fade" id="myModal6" role="dialog">` if i remove that, then i can edit each user, but with that, it only update first user.

```
$query = $handler->query('SELECT * FROM users');
<?php while($r = $query->fetch()) { ?>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal6" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                 <!-- Modal content-->
                 <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Izmeni</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p>
                                <form action="admin.php?update_id=<?php echo $r['id']; ?>" method="post">
                                    <div class="field">
                                        <center><input type="text" name="updatename" class="form-control" required="" placeholder="<?php echo $r['id']; ?>"></center><br>
                                        <center><input type="text" name="updatesurname" class="form-control" required="" placeholder="Prezime"></center><br>
                                        <center><button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Izmeni</button></center>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
 <?php } ?>
```

So, if i remove `<div class="modal fade" id="myModal6" role="dialog">` it will work, but then my form will be screwd like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ID across the page needs to be unique if it needs to be executed correctly. Or esle it will be clubbed and it will produce unforced results.

**List page:**

```
<a type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal<?php echo $r['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-info" href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
```

This will create Seperate ID for all the Popups and you can use it.

**Modified Code:**

```
$query = $handler->query('SELECT * FROM users');
<?php while($r = $query->fetch()) { ?>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal<?php echo $r['id']; ?>" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                 <!-- Modal content-->
                 <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Izmeni</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p>
                                <form action="admin.php?update_id=<?php echo $r['id']; ?>" method="post">
                                    <div class="field">
                                        <center><input type="text" name="updatename" class="form-control" required="" placeholder="<?php echo $r['id']; ?>"></center><br>
                                        <center><input type="text" name="updatesurname" class="form-control" required="" placeholder="Prezime"></center><br>
                                        <center><button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Izmeni</button></center>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: You have to call the class for the Bootstrap popup (fade) form. Don't call the ID

Comment: Glad to help you bro :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `<div class="modal fade" id="myModal6" role="dialog">` use

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal<?php echo $r['id']; ?>" role="dialog">
```

Id of the element should be unique across the whole page.

Comment: `myModal6` is the ID of form, but `$r['id']` is the ID of user, how can you mix that?

Comment: You code should generate unique id for form elements. How you will do it it's up to you. I will use id of the user as a simple approach.